# Counting inactive users based on their activity last 90 days month by month

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table with users' transactions and I'm trying to make a query that shows a number of inactive users month by month based on one condition: user has no records in the table for at least 3 months before this month, e.g. in January 2020 I want to count users that had their last transactions in September 2019, in February 2020 with last purchase in October 2019, and so on.

Example:

| user_id | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | 2020-02-04 |
| 3 | 2020-02-12 |
| 4 | 2020-03-23 |
| 5 | 2020-03-02 |
| 1 | 2020-05-11 |

Result:

| Month | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | 0 |
| ... | 0 |
| 2020-05 | 1 |
| 2020-06 | 2 |
| 2020-07 | 2 |
| 2020-08 | 0 |
| 2020-09 | 1 |

I tried something like this

```
WITH date AS
(SELECT '2020-01-01' as s UNION ALL SELECT '2020-02-01' UNION ALL SELECT '2020-03-01' UNION ALL 
SELECT '2020-04-01' UNION ALL SELECT '2020-05-01' UNION ALL SELECT '2020-06-01' UNION ALL 
SELECT '2020-07-01' UNION ALL SELECT '2020-08-01' UNION ALL SELECT '2020-09-01' UNION ALL 
SELECT '2020-10-01' UNION ALL SELECT '2020-11-01' UNION ALL SELECT '2020-12-01')
SELECT date.s, COUNT(t.customer_id)
FROM date LEFT JOIN trips t ON toDate(formatDateTime(t.booking_time, '%Y-%m-%d')) = date_sub(month, 3, toDate(date.s))
GROUP BY date.s
ORDER BY date.s
```

but it shows no results, just a blank table. How can I fix this solutions and what are the other ways to make count like that?

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this?

```
WITH
    toStartOfMonth(date) AS m
SELECT 
    user_id,
    toStartOfInterval(m - 3, INTERVAL 3 MONTH),
    count()
FROM trips
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2 ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use smth like this

```
SELECT
    max(date) AS md,
    user_id,
    d
FROM t
ARRAY JOIN arrayMap(x -> toDate(x), ['2020-01-01', '2020-05-01', '2020-06-01', '2020-07-01', '2020-08-01', '2020-09-01']) AS d
WHERE date < d
GROUP BY
    d,
    user_id
```

to calculate the last event prior to each month for each user. the use `countIf` and `group by d` to calculate the rest based on your conditions.